# MSP430G2553 recives wrong value from the MCP3464 ADC converter (SPI)

Tags: c, spi, microchip, msp430, adc

I have soldert the MCP3464 on a PCB break board and conect it with the MSP430G2553.
I then wrote a test code to see if i can write and read on the internal registers of the MCP3464. But when i try to read from it i get everytime the wrong value.

Here is what i tried:

- soldert a new MCP3464 on a new break board
- tried to find an example code for the MCP430G2553

[Datasheet ADC converter MCP3464](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/MCP3461-2-4-Two-Four-Eight-Channel-153.6-ksps-Low-Noise-16-Bit-Delta-Sigma-ADC-Data-Sheet-20006180D.pdf)

[Datasheet mircocontroller MSP430G2553](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/msp430g2553.pdf)

[Family user guide MSP430G2553](https://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau144j/slau144j.pdf?ts=1645243446189)

In this example code i try to write to the TIMER register and then read from it to see if the same value comes out, here i to send 0xA56547 but i recive 0xF7E7C0.

Here is the code:

```
#include <msp430.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#include "MCP3464_Commands.h"           // library with command's for the MCP3464

uint8_t rcv;


void init_Clock(void);
void SPI_Send(uint8_t data);
void configSPI_A(void);


void main(void)
{
    P1DIR |= BIT3;          // BIT 3 is CS
    P1OUT |= BIT3;          // CS is HIGH

    init_Clock();           // clock configuration
    configSPI_A();          // SPI A configuration


while (1)
{



    P1OUT |= BIT3;                          // CS is HIGH
    P1OUT &= ~BIT3;                         // CS is LOW
    SPI_Send(0b111000);            // Here the MSP430 sends a full reset to the MCP3464

    P1OUT |= BIT3;                          // CS is HIGH


    P1OUT &= ~BIT3;                         // CS is LOW
    SPI_Send(0b10 + 0b100000);    // Here i want to write data to the TIMER register, this is a 24 bit register

    SPI_Send(0b10100101);                   // This is the 24 bit data that i send to the MCP3464
    SPI_Send(0b01100101);
    SPI_Send(0b01000111);

    P1OUT |= BIT3;                          //CS is HIGH



    P1OUT &= ~BIT3;                         // CS is LOW

    SPI_Send(0b11 + 0b100000);     // here i want to read form the time register

    SPI_Send(0);                            // since this is a 24 bit register i send nothing and just
    SPI_Send(0);                            // read form the UCA0RXBUF what the data is in debug mode
    SPI_Send(0);

    P1OUT |= BIT3;                          // CS is HIGH

    }
}


void SPI_Send(uint8_t data)
{

    UCA0TXBUF = data;                           // data to UCA0TXBUF register
    while(UCA0STAT & UCBUSY);                   // wait until the data has bean send

    rcv = UCA0RXBUF;                            // Received data from the UCA0RXBUF to rcv

}

void configSPI_A(void)
{
    P1SEL = BIT1 + BIT2 + BIT4;             // PIN 1 2 and 4 for spi protocol
    P1SEL2 = BIT1 + BIT2 + BIT4;            // PIN 1 2 and 4 for spi protocol 2


    UCA0CTL1 |= UCSWRST;                                           //enable, usci logic held in reset state
    UCA0CTL0 |= UCMSB + UCMST + UCSYNC + UCCKPH + UCCKPL;          // SPI Mode [1.1], most significant bit first, Syncronish, master mode,
    UCA0CTL1 |= UCSSEL_2 ;                                         // select SMCLK


    UCA0BR0 = 20;                             // the clock divider is set to 20 so that the spi clock can be 800 KHz
    UCA0BR1 = 0;

    UCA0CTL1 &= ~UCSWRST;
}


// set clock to max
void init_Clock(void)
{

    WDTCTL = WDTPW + WDTHOLD;   // hold watchdog
    BCSCTL2 = SELM_0 + DIVM_0 + DIVS_0;

    if (CALBC1_16MHZ != 0xFF)
    {
        __delay_cycles(100000);
        DCOCTL = 0x00;
        BCSCTL1 = CALBC1_16MHZ;
        DCOCTL = CALDCO_16MHZ;
    }

}
```

**Update**

Here are some screenshot that i took from my osciloscope

- blue is CS
- yelow is clock
- green is MISO
- purple is MOSI

[Full image of SPI comunication](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJO0R.png)

[Zomed in image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYfew.png)

[Zomed in image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVOSG.png)

[Zomed in image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59uYe.png)

Comment: We cannot effectively help with issues that may well involve hardware.  We cannot attach meter/scope probes to narrow down the problem:(

Comment: SLAU144J, pg. 445: Doesn't you need to set UCSSELx values for an appropriate clock?